# word properties in background shorthand not working

Tags: css

The other topics don't seem to solve my case.
My code looks like this:

```
body {
    background: url("th.jpg") initial/cover no-repeat #fff00f;
}
```

were I to replace `initial` with let's say `top right` it would work though `initial` is a property value of *background-position*. Were I to type `top right/initial`it wouldn't work either even though initial is a property value of *background-size*. No need to say it'd be the same if I wrote alone "initial".
What's the problem? I use the order referenced on: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

Comment: try individual background property

Comment: It works in that case, but I want to understand why it doesn't work in shorthand version